# How to round percents

Tags: decimal-expansion

Suppose there is election such that $n$ votes are given to $m$ candidates. I would like to express the results of elections in two decimal places, like

```
0.13
0.15
0.03
...
```

Suppose further that after listing those numbers, the decimal numbers add to, say 1.03 due to rounding offs. What is the correct method to express the result? Should I divide the 0.03 to three candidates who got highest number of votes to minimize the relative error or what kind of method I should use?

Comment: You're rounding, I think it's fine to have the total not add up to $1$.  Otherwise you have to make arbitrary decisions that are not necessarily right or wrong.  I would say that you should 1) only round up or down in the least significant digit (e.g. if Bob gets 15.657%, which you then round to 15.66%, you shouldn't "fix" Bob's value by giving him 15.67%, it should either by 15.66% or 15.65%) and 2) your rounding should preserve the correct order (e.g. if Bob gets 15.657% and Lucy gets 15.656%, your rounding scheme shouldn't give Bob 15.65 and Lucy 15.66).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to say *"Components may not sum to $1$* (or $100\%$) *due to rounding"*. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Components+may+not+sum+to+totals+because+of+rounding%22) suggests this kind of statement is common.

This was discussed in a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227215/how-to-deal-with-the-sum-of-rounded-percentage-not-being-100).

If you are interested, I once wrote a [note on the likely distribution of rounding errors](http://www.se16.info/hgb/rounding.pdf). In it I looked at the UK general elections in 2001 and 2005, where there were a total of $6873$ candidates in $1305$ constituency contests.  The rounded percentages per candidate added up to

```
 total    times
 99.8%      11  
 99.9%     261
100.0%     774
100.1%     249
100.2%      10
```